# Draw CGGradient On Enclosed Path

Tags: ios, quartz-graphics, cgpath

How does one draw a CGGradient on an enclosed path within a view? I have attempted to draw the gradient, however, it is drawn on the view itself, rather than only within a CGPath that I am filling inside the view. I would like to draw a gradient on the filled path only, and not on the view itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Save the context's state.
2. Set the path as a clip region in your context.
3. Draw the gradient.
4. Restore the context's state.

Example:

```
CGContextSaveGState(context);
CGContextAddPath(context, myPath);
CGContextClip(context);
CGContextDrawLinearGradient(context, gradient, startPoint, endPoint, kNilOptions);
CGContextRestoreGState(context);
```

Comment: Thanks. How does one draw a gradient with a central color and the same color on the top and bottom? I have the array as such CFArrayRef colors = (__bridge CFArrayRef) [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)lightGradientColor.CGColor,
                                               (id)darkGradientColor.CGColor, (id)lightGradientColor.CGColor,
                                               nil];  but the light color is only at the top.

Comment: You should post a new question for that.